# Customized UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can i customize a UITableviewCell, as i want to see a label, date and picture in a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link.

There you'll find how to make a custom cell with Interface Builder and use it in XCode for your application.

http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

Answer (score 3):

There are two options (may be more). You could use the native UITableViewCell properties to add content to the cell, or create a custom cell (by that I mean, add your own subviews to the Cell). To get started try the first one, it is simple elegant and the results will be quite good. For example try the following cell creation method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // notice the Style. The UITableViewCell has a few very good styles that make your cells look very good with little effort
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    // In my case I get the data from the elements array that has a bunch on dictionaries
    NSDictionary *d = [elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // the textLabel is the main label
    cell.textLabel.text = [d objectForKey:@"title"];

    // the detailTextLabel is the subtitle
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [d objectForKey:@"date"];

    // Set the image on the cell. In this case I load an image from the bundle
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fsaint.png"];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize UITableViewCell using either [Interface Builder](http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) or through [Code](http://icodeblog.com/2008/09/02/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of overriding the UITableViewCell class, and doing custom drawing in self.contentView.  This technique is a little more complicated, but it leads to much better scrolling performance.

For example, lets say you override your cell, and have 3 properties on it like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *userPic;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *label;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *date;
```

Then you can draw them in the cell using the (drawRect:) function:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [userPic drawInRect: CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 50)];
    [label drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(70, 5) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
    [date drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(70, 30) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
  }
```

For more examples try checking out this framework that uses this style: https://github.com/andrewzimmer906/XCell